# TDLib GetUser return user's configured display name instead display name from address book

Tags: c#, telegram, tdlib

We are using custom Telegram client (NOT A BOT!!) based on TDLib (.NET implementation). User have around 500 contacts in the address book, and it synced with the Telegram (as usual). Our Telegram client handling around 700-800 messages daily, and for 2 or 3 messages the GetUser call return a weird data.
Sample: user have his account in Telegram and put the first name as "War Lord 15". If the user is not in the address book of the client, then this name will be showed as FistName of the TDApi.User object.

Client put this account to the address book and set name as "John Dow". Now the GetUser will return this as FirstName of the TDApi.User object.

But sometime (not very often, like 1 or 2 calls per week) the GetUser call returns the profile name ("War Lord 15") instead configured in address book ("John Dow").

There is nothing special in the call:

```
 private  TdClient _client;

...
_client = new TdClient();
...
UserModel GetUser(long userId){
     var tdUser = await _client.GetUserAsync(userId);
     ...
}
```

The userId taken from the received message:

```
var tdChat = await _client.ExecuteAsync(new TdApi.GetChat { ChatId = chatId });
if(tdChat.Type is TdApi.ChatType.ChatTypePrivate privateChat){
    GetUser(privateChat.userId);
}
```

It doesn't matter when user was added to the Telegram or address book: we faced with this even for contacts who several years existing in Telegram and added to address book more than year ago.

This behavior started around end of the last year.
Does anyone faced with the same?